# Playing HTML5 hls video from Android webview

Tags: android, html, video, webview, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to play an embedded video on a website within a webview but after the page loads the video player area is just a blank space. The video appears when the website is opened from a regular Chrome browser on an Android device but is blank within the app's webview. I have set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the manifest and below is the webview code. Anyone have any ideas why it won't appear in a webview? Thanks

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(selectedItem.getLink());
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

It's working fine. Try to run the code on an actual device. You can check this demo project: [HTML5-Video-Android demo](https://github.com/jakirseu/HTML5-Video-Android)

Comment: Thanks Jakir, the video in the asset folder in the sample seems to be a basic mp4, not HLS stream. I don't have an issue with simple mp4 files.